# Training and validation loss sometimes not decreasing in Keras dense layer with the same data and random seed

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to use a Multi-Layer-Perceptron in Keras (Dense layer) to map 6 inputs to 1 output. For doing this I use the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define the file paths
MLSupvervised_input_data_file_path = r"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MLSupvervised_input_data.csv"
MLSupervised_output_data_file_path = r"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MLSupervised_output_data.csv"

# Read MLSupvervised_input_data and MLSupvervised_input_data from a CSV file as a NumPy array
MLSupvervised_input_data = np.loadtxt(MLSupvervised_input_data_file_path, delimiter=";", dtype=np.float64)
MLSupervised_output_data = np.loadtxt(MLSupervised_output_data_file_path, delimiter=";", dtype=np.float64)

#Standardize the data
scaler_standardized_X = StandardScaler()
MLSupvervised_input_data = scaler_standardized_X.fit_transform(MLSupvervised_input_data)

scaler_standardized_Y = StandardScaler()
MLSupervised_output_data = scaler_standardized_Y.fit_transform(MLSupervised_output_data.reshape(-1, 1))

#Split data
index_X_Train_End = int(0.7 * len(MLSupvervised_input_data))
index_X_Validation_End = int(1.0 * len(MLSupvervised_input_data))

X_train = MLSupvervised_input_data[0: index_X_Train_End]
X_valid = MLSupvervised_input_data[index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]
Y_train = MLSupervised_output_data[0: index_X_Train_End]
Y_valid = MLSupervised_output_data[index_X_Train_End: index_X_Validation_End]



# Set the random seed
seed_value = 3
np.random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)


#Define optimizer
optimizer_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.001)

#Define model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(6,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(80, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')])

#Run the model
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))


# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Mean Sqaurred Error')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

I also have uploaded the input data here: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/d53U4e5A#link

The problem is that when using the code multiple times with the same data and the same random_seed, sometimes the training results look okay and sometimes the training and validation loss remain constant and nothing happens.

Here you see the plots from the training with okay results:
[image]

And here with bad results (constant training and validation losses):
[image]

Do you have any idea as to why this is happening? The strange aspect is that I use the same random_seed and the same data and still the training performance differs extremely strongly and for me this behaviour occurs kind of "randomly", meaning I have no clue why sometimes the training is okay and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

- The thumb rule for standardization (not a rule, but it's a good practice) that you should first separate the X_train and X_test and then use standardization or normalization techniques over them.
- Also try using `Linear` activation function in last layer as you are interested in getting outputs and not the positive outputs only. Because that's what the `relu` is doing. Also, your `loss function` and `metric` are not matching.
- Finally, about the randomness, if you fix `random_state` while splitting the data or any random value that you are using then you will get same score every time. But randomness could be good sometimes. Also, if you make sure that you are getting the same rows every time you split the data, then you won't be getting different results.

Hope I answered your questions.

Comment: @Harshard: Thanks Harshad for your answer. To your points 1) When I standardize the data after plitting the standardization will only consider a fraction of the data. So we have 2 different scalars then for the input data x and 2 for y. Why should this be beneficial. 2) Actually the final output should only be positive and `relu` is a linear function as far as I understand. 3) The most important remark: My question is not primarily about the randomness itself in traning which is not a bad thing. It is about the reason why in several cases "nothing" happens when training (no decrease of loss)

Comment: About `RELU`, it will only give you output when it's positive, and it will zero everything else. That's why I suggested `linear` function there. About standardization, why we are only fitting on X_train is because we want our test/validation data to resemble the train set. By the way, we will only have 1 scalar not 2. Because we are fitting our `StandardScalar` on `X_train` and then transforming other datasets (X_valid and X_test). Finally why thisis the case, because linear models have certain requirements to fulfill to make them work better. If you still get confused, then let me know.

Comment: Thanks Harshad  for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. To be totally honest, I am very confused about all of my 3 points. 1) Why shall I not use `Relu` in the output layer when my output labels are all positive (see linked dataset)? 2) When only having 1 `StandardScalar ` for `X_train ` and 'X_valid ` (any maybe `X_test`), what difference does it make to scale before or after the splitting? 3) How can these 2 points explain why in some cases nothing happens during the training and the error function remains constant

Comment: If all your outputs arr positive, then it's fine. But I was suggesting it because it's a good practice. `StandardScaling` converts your data into a gaussian format. StandardScaler removes the mean and scales each feature/variable to unit variance. This operation is performed feature-wise in an independent way. StandardScaler can be influenced by outliers.

Comment: Neural networks often benefit from scaling the data for several reasons: 1. Most neural network optimization algorithms, such as gradient descent, are sensitive to the scale of the input features. Features with larger scales can dominate the learning process, making it difficult for the network to converge. Scaling the data helps mitigate this issue by bringing all features to a similar scale.

Comment: 2.Certain activation functions used in neural networks, such as sigmoid or tanh, are sensitive to the scale of the input. When features have different scales, it can result in uneven activation levels across neurons, impacting the learning process. Scaling the data ensures that the input falls within the desired range of the activation function, promoting better convergence.

Comment: 3.Scaling the data helps meet the assumptions and can lead to better weight initialization and training. 4. By scaling the data, you create a more favorable environment for the neural network to learn efficiently and effectively. It helps avoid issues like slow convergence, vanishing/exploding gradients, and uneven feature influences. Scaling is a common preprocessing step that helps improve the performance and stability of neural network models. If you still have questions then do ask.

Comment: it's important to consider whether ReLU is the most appropriate choice for your specific problem. While ReLU can work in this scenario, it still lacks an upper bound, which means the predicted values could potentially be very large. Depending on the nature of your data and the specific requirements of your problem, it might be more suitable to use an activation function that provides a better range for your predictions.

Comment: If you want to constrain the output values to a specific range, such as positive values up to a certain threshold, you might consider using a different activation function. For example, you could use a modified ReLU variant called the "clipped ReLU," where the output is limited to a maximum value. Another option is to use an activation function like the sigmoid or hyperbolic tangent (as mentioned in the previous response) to ensure that the output is bounded within a specific range.

Comment: Ultimately, the choice of activation function in the final layer depends on the specific requirements and constraints of your regression problem. It is often helpful to experiment with different activation functions and evaluate their performance on a validation set to determine the most suitable option for your task.

Comment: Thanks Harshad for your answer. Acutally I never questioned and asked for why I should do the scaling in general. My question is, why shall it make a difference if I apply the scaling before or after the splitting when I use the same scaler. For me, this does not make any difference. Further, my main question still remains unanswered: Why does the training in several cases not improve the error functions at all while sometimes the same random_seed, model and data lead to a clearly visible training process (decrease of the error function)